# why Telerik control won't work within update panel when trigger is set on "selection_changed" event of asp Calendar control?

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I am using Telerik's radial linear gauge control under asp update panel in my ASP page.
and its trigger is set on calendar's selection changed event.
Selection changed event is fired and executed successfully, but after that it throws error as "Microsoft JScriptruntime error: Arg: Fraction out of range(0 to 1 allowed).

Unfortunately I can not post image as this is my first post.

my Home.aspx code for both controls is as follows:

```
<td>
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updtPanelCalendar" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
                        UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:Calendar ID="calActivityEvent" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="Black"
                                BorderStyle="Solid" CellSpacing="1" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="9pt" ForeColor="Black"
                                Height="250px" NextPrevFormat="ShortMonth" Width="330px" Style="margin-left: 20px">
                                <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#0066ff" ForeColor="BlueViolet" />
                                <TodayDayStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="White" />
                                <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
                                <DayStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                                <NextPrevStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White" />
                                <DayHeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#333333" Height="8pt" />
                                <TitleStyle BackColor="#333399" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="12pt"
                                    ForeColor="White" Height="12pt" />
                            </asp:Calendar>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                        <Triggers>
                            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="calActivityEvent" EventName="SelectionChanged" />
                        </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel> 
                </td>
```

and i have created and placed Telerik control at calendar's event.
It works fine before using update panel. But not works in the Update panel.
Why this happens?

Comment: What is the stack trace of the error? Does it originate from the gauge or elsewhere?

Are your Telerik controls updated to their latest vesrion (Q3 2014 SP1 at the time of writing) and if not - does upgrading help?

Comment: @rdmptn There is no stack trace error in server side as the event fires correctly and code also get executed fine. Problem is that the changes made by code are not reflected or shown on the browser side as no page update takes place at browser side.

Somehow I managed by setting different triggers but still it won't work in the IE.

When IE used as default browser Error is thrown in Visual Studio IDE as follows " Microsoft JScript runtime error: Arg: Fraction out of range (0 to 1 allowed) "  and possible options on the error prompt are "Break / Contiunue / Ignore "
Error line is ---

Comment: @rdmptn Error line is--->  if (node.nodeType === 1) {
File name is-->TransientScriptDocument57.axd
Now I don't know why this happens.

Comment: TransientScriptDocument57.axd does not sound like a Telerik resource handler so you should look into any other extensions and tools in use. Still, without a stack trace this error is far too vague for any help. Create a sample that shows the problem and send it to Telerik if you feel this is a problem with their components.

Comment: @rdmptn As I can not share screen shot here, But Thank you for the suggestion I will think over it. :)